# If gossip is always negative, what is the correct positive word?

Tags: single-word-requests, philosophy

With the concept in philosophy of shame in the negative, and positive, what would gossip in the positive be called?

As an example:

> I just found out that they were dating.

(A factual statement being told to someone they both know.)

Comment: I see definitions of *gossip* that are neutral or more favorable.

Comment: Gossip _isn't_ always negative; it's just spreading personal information that hasn't been confirmed by the people in question.

Comment: Whether starting dating or breaking up, they're both gossip. (and in both instances the situation could be either good or bad). What is negative about gossip is the intention. "Did you see the new car in their driveway? Scandalous. Where did they get the money for that, I wonder."

Comment: Even if you reject "gossip", the question can be answered with a [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/gossip).

Comment: One needs to distinguish between the 'negativeness' of content and motivation / sensitivity in passing on the information. 'Passing on good news, with permission' could work.

Comment: I agree with you that _gossip_ has generally pejorative overtones—and looking at the list of more-or-less relevant synonyms that Laurel provide, I don't see any that are truly on point **and** positive. The closest ones in sense (_chitchat_, _chatter_, _scuttlebutt_) are at best neutral, and others are themselves quite negative. What you'd want is something more along the lines of "grapevine wisdom" or "crowd-sourced insight"—neither of which is even remotely a common phrase. The phrase that I think comes closest to putting a positive spin on _gossip_ is "a little bird told me."

Comment: The word "rumor" is not exactly the same as gossip but close and has a neutral connotation, I believe.

Comment: I was told by a priest that gossip involves calumny

Comment: Consider *juicy bit of gossip*. It's obviously positive for gossipers, if not for subjects.

Comment: Factual statement can be considered *information*, or more informally *info*.

Comment: For a SWR, a sentence with a blank where the word is to be inserted is required, a c.

Comment: I think the question is unclearly stated.  Are we looking for something that _reflects positively_ on the person being spoken about, something confirmed "straight from the horse's mouth," or both?

Comment: In the appropriate contexts, the term _networking_ is used with positive connotations to describe informal social behavior and conversations, not usually involving calumny, or even implied criticism.

Comment: I cannot understand the meaning of your words "With the concept in philosophy of shame in the negative, and positive, what would gossip in the positive be called?" But I think that a current slang word for positive gossip might be "buzz," and an old-fashioned word was "scuttlebutt." I see at MW that the latter is simply defined as "gossip," but the examples I'm seeing at the bottom of the entry are positive.

Answer (score 1):

**Small talk**

OED:

> **1. Light talk or conversation, esp. polite conversation about unimportant or uncontroversial matters, as engaged in on social
> occasions. Also figurative.** *not to have any small talk: to lack the ability to engage successfully in such conversation.*
>
> 1650   J. Trapp Solomonis Παναρετος (Prov. ix. 13) 84   *Folly is full of words, and of a lavish tongue: her factours are extreme talkative..A great deale of small talk you shall usually have from
> them.*
>
> 1810   G. Crabbe Borough iii. 33   *As your Tea you sip, While the
> Town Small-talk flows from lip to lip.*
>
> 1957   New Scientist 28 Nov. 21/2   *He doesn't gossip, has no small talk, is driven by neither social, financial nor political ambition.*

Comment: As far as I can tell, small talk isn't necessarily about people, let alone their private lives. The iconic example of small talk is talking about the weather.

Answer (score 1):

Neutral in tone

- Banter
- Chit-chat

Formal in tone

- Discussion

Negative in tone (sometimes)

- [Tittle-tattle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tittle-tattle)

Positive in tone

- [Persiflage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/persiflage) (Good-natured banter; raillery. frivolous, lighthearted discussion of a topic)

Answer (score 0):

**Intelligence.**

[From Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intelligence) :

> a : information, news  b : information concerning an enemy or possible
> enemy or an area also : an agency engaged in obtaining such
> information

But, the word can be used in other places as well. For example :

*Tonight's intelligence reports that the Boss of company A is seen dining with the Finance Manager of company B.*

or

*Recent intelligence indicates that the enemy has crossed the river. The rumors of them deploying anti-personnel mines turned out to be true.*

Comment: Hello, Sean. 'Gossip' and 'intelligence' are almost polar opposites in register.